# How could a cold weather creature survive in a hot climate?

Tags: science-based, biology, clothing

I was thinking about how one of the reasons humans have been so successful is that we can adapt to live almost anywhere. A big part of this is that we can put on more clothes when it's cold, and take them off when it's hot. How could a creature that is naturally suited to cold weather keep themselves cool so that they could live in a warmer climate?

I'm looking for an answer that doesn't require constant energy to function. I.e., no air-conditioned power suits.

Comment: Have it stay in the water during daytime and leave the water at night to eat (like hippos do).

Comment: [Shave](http://i.imgur.com/pGXSiBl.jpg). Yes, that is a bear.

Answer (score 4):

I have lived in Thailand, and observed some unfortunate Husky dogs who were brought from their native sub-Arctic to Thailand's full tropical climate.

Dog 1 we referred to as Maa Rawn ("Hot Dog" in Thai) - he spent most of his time lying in the shade, sweating, and was only active at night, when it was a bit cooler.

Dog 2 we referred to as Maa Talae ("Sea Dog") - he dipped in the ocean about every 45 minutes during the day, and was basically always wet and evaporating. He was able to be just as active as the native short-haired dogs from neighboring properties.

Comment: Here in Texas, dogs with a heavy undercoat are often shaved in the summer.

Answer (score 3):

If it survives, how is it not (also) a warm-weather creature?

It may have adaptations for coping with cold but does not *require* being cold. The original home may be colder part of the year and the adaptations are not needed in summer, so it lives in more comfort but carries around unneded adaptations.  So when moving to a new area, it’s like summer all the time.

Now, in a few generations it would lose the adaptations. Or it would nit compete well with native forms, since it wastes resources on unneeded features.  But, maybe the same features can find a different use in the new environment. A notable example is the camel which we associate with deserts, but the signature adaptations were originally evolved for dealing with *cold*.  But snowshoes are handy in dunes too, etc.